# Rotate nav links when scrolling the page - CSS, jQ

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a single page web template where I am trying to rotate the links depending on the section that I am viewing.

**.html**

```
 <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
      <div id="nav-anchor"></div>
        <ul id="top-menu" class="primary-nav">
          <li><a href="#nas">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#intro">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#calendar">Calendar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>
```

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $sections = $('.d');


  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    var $currentSection

    $sections.each(function(){

      var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;

      if( divPosition - 1 < currentScroll ){
        $currentSection = $(this);

        }

      var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('active');

    })

  });
});
```

**.css**

```
.active {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
```

So far is not working for me. Active class is applied to my links but css is not applying and I can't see why?

Comment: Can you provide the whole HTML?

Comment: It would help if you included a working snippet with your question

Comment: Did you remember to add the import for jquery in your <head>?  

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Srax yes I did added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add some position and block CSS if you are adding transtions/transform to inline tags

```
a {psoition: relative; display: block;}
```